# Installation error in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried installing ROS through terminal on my new ubuntu 12.10 installation. But i could not install the package. Help me. I have been using ROS on 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46308/installation-error-in-ubuntu-12.10/) by [aravindev](https://answers.ros.org/users/3416/aravindev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know ROS is not released from 12.10, yet. You will need to build ROS from sources.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-25**:
According to REP-0003, Fuerte won't be released for 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**you can watch this vedio for ROS installation :**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IJDmd0DGe0&list=PLDC89965A56E6A8D6&index=1&feature=plpp_video

**if you faced any error write it :)**

---

Originally posted by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) with karma: 464 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2